# Kendo UI Column with Detail Table

Tags: jquery, charts, kendo-ui

I am currently displaying a Kendo UI chart with a standard HTML table underneath it. Does anyone know of a way where I can specify each category to be displayed with a specific width? The reason why I would like to do this is because I would like that the category labels match up exactly with the table headers beneath it so that it's easy for the user to see the data in detail.

Here is what I currently have. You will notice that as more dates get added the more it gets out of sync. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

[current sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3ZoJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Set a width on the `td`'s of your HTML table equal to the column width of your graph.

For example if the columns of your graph are 35px wide, then in your css:

```
td.tableDataBelowMyGraph{
width: 35px;
}
```

As it stands, your `td`'s width are being set by their contents.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I know the width of the column in the graph? That's what I am having a hard time doing. Figuring out what the width of the column is of the graph and how to set it.